# php find image link with anchor inside a div with specific class name

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink

I need to find the image link and a `href` inside a specific `div`. The `div` has a class name. I have customized following code but cant get those images only inside a div with class name media. Here is an example of the HTML structure

```
<div class="media">
   <a href="http://www.images.img/image.jpg" title="">
        <img id="image" src="http://www.images.img/zoomin/image.jpg.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[class="media"]//a[@href]//img') as $img) {

        for ($link = $img; $link->tagName !== 'a'; $link = $link->parentNode);
        
        $output[] = array(
            'href' => $link->getAttribute('href'),
            'src'  => $img->getAttribute('src'),
            'alt'  => $img->getAttribute('alt'),
        );
    }
```

But it finds all images with the anchor tag and any `div`.

Can somebody provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="media"]//a[@href]//img/ancestor::a[1]') as $link) {

    foreach($xpath->query('//a[@href="' . $link->getAttribute('href') . '"]//img') as $img) {
        $output[] = array(
            'href' => $link->getAttribute('href'),
            'src'  => $img->getAttribute('src'),
            'alt'  => $img->getAttribute('alt')
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you've missed `@` for `class` attribute. Second, you don't need to traverse the tree up, XPath can do that for you:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="media"]//a[@href]//img/ancestor::a[1]') as $link) {
    $output[] = array(
        'href' => $link->getAttribute('href'),
        'src'  => $img->getAttribute('src'),
        'alt'  => $img->getAttribute('alt'),
    );
}
```

Comment: You aren't getting the image attributes.

Comment: Right, missed the fact that you used both image and link in the output.